# Add a Foreign Key in PgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, pgadmin

I have `studidtemplates` table below:

[image]

`template_id` is the primary_key

[image]

I want to create a new table referencing `template_id` as a `foreign key`. It is named `studidtemplatetextelements`. See image below:

[image]

I created a column `template_id` in the second table and want to make it a foreign key referencing `template_id` in `studidtemplates` table. I did it by clicking the button in the `Constraints` tab,pointed by an arrow in the image below.

[image]

I notice something different. In 'Referencing' option there's no `template_id` option available. See image below:

[image]

Where am I missing?

Answer (score 56):

In pgAdmin 4, here are the steps:

1. Right-click on the table and select **Properties**.
2. Within the dialog that appears, click **Constraints** / **Foreign Key**.
3. Click the **+** icon on the upper-right of the Foreign key table.
4. Click the ***pencil icon***, which is all the way on the left of the new row that now appears in the Foreign key table.
5. Under the *General* tab, give your foreign key a name (I follow [this convention](https://gist.github.com/popravich/d6816ef1653329fb1745) of *{tablename}_{columnname}_fkey*).
6. Under the *Columns* tab, select your references.
7. Click the **+** icon to the right of the "Local column".
8. Click the **Save** button at the bottom.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: pgAdmin 4 foreign key dialog]

Comment: **Local column**: the foreign key column in your *current table* (user_id_fkey), **References**: the *table* which has the primary key that your foreign key is referencing (users), **Referencing**: the actual *column* in that table that the foreign key is referencing (id)

Answer (score 3):

The columns listed under `Referencing` are columns that belong to the selected table.

You need to change the selected table in `References` as follows:
[image]

Which version of pgAdmin are you using? The References textbox was moved to Columns tab in version [1.16](http://www.pgadmin.org/visualtour16.php) :

> On the foreign key properties dialog, the "References" table textbox
>   has been moved to the third tab

Comment: Thank you but I dont have the 'References' dropdown option. What shall I do?

Comment: i have Version 1.14.2, where will I find 'References' dropdown in version 1.14.2?

Comment: I found references in the 'Definition' Tab. Thanks for giving me an idea. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

The more convenient, for me, is the Query Tool (for the specific database one wants to work with).

Access the Query Tool by clicking the icon or `Alt`+`Shift`+`Q`

[image]

As, in my case, I wanted to add relationship between `products` (through a field to be added named `added_by`) and `users` (specifically, `id`), I've used [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) the following script

```
ALTER TABLE public.products ADD COLUMN added_by integer;
ALTER TABLE public.products ADD CONSTRAINT products_added_by_fkey FOREIGN KEY (added_by) REFERENCES public.users (id);
```

Now one can see the field `added_by` and the constraint `products_added_by_fkey`

[image]

If one checks the properties of the constraint, one will see, in the Columns tab, the following

[image]

---

**Notes**:

- If the issue is just to add the foreign key constraint, assuming the field already exists, see the last line in the previous script, or the following example given in [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-altertable.html):

  ```
  ALTER TABLE distributors ADD CONSTRAINT distfk FOREIGN KEY (address) REFERENCES addresses (address);
  ```